# How to open email client as MailItem in Windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, email-client

**I am looking for a way to handle opening the default mail client's mail item populated with content(Attachments) using windows service.**

***Considering the below ways I've tried:***

- **Outlook Interop:** does not work, since i am trying to integrate with email client through windows service, "Outlook Interop" does not support non-interactive application.
- **Mailto:** could not add an attachments.
- **ActiveX:** It is only available in Internet Explorer.

*Is there another way to handle my requirements?*

Comment: The problem is, you're giving us "requirements" that assume a particular form of solution, and as you're discovering, it's not working out well. What is the *actual* requirement? Is it to send an email with attachments? (no need to go via a client application there) Is it to prompt "the" user for input? (Not possible for various reasons from services)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i'm looking for a way to launch the email client at client machine

Comment: Well that's *not going to happen*. Windows Services run in a *non-interactive* session, that's separate from any user sessions for users who are currently logged in. If you want code running in those sessions, you have to arrange for that to happen separately e.g. by having a startup program that communicates with the service, so that the service can ask one or more of them (if any are running) to launch the program instead. And then you have to decide what to do for 0 users and multiple users.